# Rails, Postgres, EC2/AWS: Database Config Does Not Specify Adapter Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect my Rails app to an EC2 instance that contains a PG database. I've already checked with Navicat that I can connect to the database given the EC2 details. The issue is that when run locally the Rails app can't be viewed; it throws the error "database configuration does not specify adapter". A similar issue is thrown when I try a database migration. I haven't even tried to push this up to my Rails EC2 since it isn't working locally.

My database.yml file looks like this:

```
production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: postgres
 host: ec2-54-197-115-117.compute-1.amazonaws.com
 pool: 10
 port: 5432 (have both included and removed this line)
 username: a database username for security
 password: the password associated with that user
```

My gem files include the gem pg.

For the database name I just wrote what it had in Navicat, but perhaps there's an official name associated with it I should be using; if so, how would I find it? The host I got from the EC2 details. And the username and password were the ones I set with the postgres database via unix.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Edit:

Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed! I had forgotten to create an actual DB after setting up the PG; I changed the name in my database.yml file to reflect the new db name. Also, I needed to set on my Rails app environment directly (I thought Apache did this automatically w/Passenger) with "export RAILS_ENV=production". I thought it was still broken when I restarted my server and nothing had changed, but I just had to restart the console. Hope this helps someone else out too!

Comment: Thanks for submitting the solution - it helped me big-time!  To get mine to work, I had to add the name of the db to the hostname to make it work; in other words, in the RDS management console, the "Endpoint" was "staging.blabla.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:5432".  I removed the :5432 part, but left in "staging.", which is the name of my database.  Just FWIW!